# How to know if IE is on its latest version?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer

I can see my IE version from the About IE window, it shows 11.0.9600.18697, however I don't know if it is the latest version.

I have been searching on Google, but found nothing, there's no such information anywhere include Microsoft websites.

Weird enough, any help?

Comment: See [Wikipedia: Internet Explorer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer)

Comment: @biswa, thanks, I found it here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_11